# How to show lists in snapshot.data in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and I am learning APIs. My API model has a list named result. Can you please tell me how can I display that list and all other variables inside it by using snapshot.data
I am trying to declare
snapshot.data!.result but it is not working. Please give me the solution to this problem

Model code is below

```
class LeaguesModel {
  LeaguesModel({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  int success;
  List<Result> result;

  factory LeaguesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LeaguesModel(
    success: json["success"],
    result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    required this.leagueKey,
    required this.leagueName,
    required this.countryKey,
    required this.countryName,
    required this.leagueLogo,
    required this.countryLogo,
  });

  String leagueKey;
  String leagueName;
  String countryKey;
  String countryName;
  String leagueLogo;
  String countryLogo;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
    leagueKey: json["league_key"],
    leagueName: json["league_name"],
    countryKey: json["country_key"],
    countryName: json["country_name"],
    leagueLogo: json["league_logo"],
    countryLogo: json["country_logo"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "league_key": leagueKey,
    "league_name": leagueName,
    "country_key": countryKey,
    "country_name": countryName,
    "league_logo": leagueLogo,
    "country_logo": countryLogo,
  };
  static List<Result> jsontoApiModel(List<dynamic> emote) => emote.map<Result>((item) => Result.fromJson(item)).toList();
}
```

Comment: where did you call API?

Comment: I have made api service file and I am calling the api there

Comment: i mean, can you provide any snippet code? because the model code is nothing wrong